# Cached HTACCESS files

Tags: .htaccess, caching

Earlier today I asked a question on SO regarding a redirect in the htaccess file. The answer given to me was actually correct, but because I had failed to clear my cache, my browser was still using a cached version of the htaccess file without my update. After clearing my cache, the redirect worked as expected. I've just installed an SSL certificate for a different client and added some rules to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. However, I'm thinking about the issue I had this morning. The customer, as well as their return visitors, would have cached the old htaccess file and therefore won't use the updated version. If this was a stylesheet or an image, I'd just add a version number, change the file name, or change the path, to "force" the update. I obviously can't do that here.  Is there anything that can be done to force return users to use the updated htaccess file?

Comment: just to be clear, the browser isn't caching your htaccess file, it's caching the redirect itself.

Comment: Aaaahhh...it makes sense that it would be done that way.  So new rules that I've added would be followed, but old rules that I've removed might still have an effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about other peoples cache I'm afraid. Eventually the cache will refresh and display the new changes. All it takes is a refresh of the page.

You ***can*** tell your website not to cache by using:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1
Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
```

But I don't really see much point in doing that unless you're making constant changes to said page. If a client asks you to make a change that requires their cache to be reset, then just tell them to do so, so that they can see it.

Comment: Good to know that that there's a way to tell a website not to cache, though I agree there isn't much point to implementing that.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No problem, the only time I tell my website not to cache is usually a page that other people cannot access and I am running a lot of tests on. Which is very handy to be honest!